Why are my characters frozen, but only 1 is moving?
1/5 of my characters move after a certain frame. Does anyone have any suggestions as to why this is happening? I have attached a link to what I am experiencing. https://youtu.be/bF6KvKw0QAw
Here is my file. https://mega.nz/file/QedyXJIT#XSi4DnKCqE4jC2i1SUECSQj8rCOTrVeCw_deTNlzCaw

Please upload your file to blend-exchange.com so it is easier for other people to help you.

Got it. It is very large though, so I will upload to mega.

Edited post with file

Now that I am looking at it more, I realise that keyframes cut off after 4144 frames. Odd.

It's simply because there are no more keyframes for these armature from the frame 4144:


I dont know what happened. I will try just simply reinstating my motion data I guess.
